# How to manually build OpenCV to work with ROS?

Tags: robotic-arm, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since ROS doesn't have binary package for ARM, I cannot use "apt-get install ros-groovy-opencv2" to download and install OpenCV libraries for ROS ("E: Unable to locate package" will appear). Can anyone give me some hints to manually download, install and wrap OpenCV libraries with ROS?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57301/how-to-manually-build-opencv-to-work-with-ros?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't done anything similar with groovy, but I think it should work more-or-less the same, since it's all CMake based. When I wanted to install OpenCV with CUDA, I did the process below. Note: I am a novice at building with CMake, so there are probably better ways of doing this.

1. Install OpenCV to a specific directory following the instructions on their website.
2. Create a CMakeModule folder within your working program directory, find a version of FindOpenCV.cmake to copy into that folder, then specify the path to OpenCV by adding the line:

   set(OpenCV_DIR "/directory/to/opencv2")
3. In your program's CMake file, add:

   SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
       "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules/")

   find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
   include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   add_definitions(${OpenCV_DEFINITIONS})
   MESSAGE(STATUS "OpenCV at: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

   **more code**

   target_link_libraries(executable_name ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

There might be some specifics that are incorrect, but I think the general idea should work.

---

Originally posted by [stantol](https://answers.ros.org/users/2884/stantol/) with karma: 146 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-03-06**:
Thanks for your reply! I will try it. By the way, which opencv version do you suggest for ARM?

**Comment by [stantol](https://answers.ros.org/users/2884/stantol/) on 2013-03-06**:
I have no experience with ARM processors, so I can't offer any advice.